# Spatial join error 000426

Tags: spatial-join

I ran the tool Spatial Join(Analysis), 
target and joined features are line feature class, 
the join operation is Join one to one, 
I set a merge rule(sum) in one of my fields(the type of the field is double)
and the match option is share a line segment with

I get ''error 000426 out of memory''. 
Is there any way to avoid it? 
I ran the tool with only a few lines and it works fine.

Comment: Please add more details about your question. What tool are you using and methodology you are following ?

Comment: Sounds like you should try it with less data. But to get real help you need to provide more Information.

Comment: is there a limitation on the input data?

Comment: I assume you're using ArcGIS, and this isn't an ArcGIS support forum, so please edit your question with more info and tags to sort by.